# R Data Transformation

Tags: r, transformation, transactional

I have a data frame with three columns that captures transactional data, including CustomerName, OrderDate and name of the Product(s) that have been purchased. I have to transform the dataframe into another dataframe with a format such that all the items purchased by a customer on a single date are in one row.

As I'm dealing with a large data set, is there an efficient way to this transformation, hopefully without using for loops.

Additionally, the number of columns for the products in the data frame must be equal to the maximum number of products bought by any customer on any single day. Please find an example of data frame before and after the transformation

Original Data:

```
data <- data.frame(Customer  = c("John", "John", "John", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Sally", "Sally", "Sally", "Sally"),
                   OrderDate = c("1-Oct", "2-Oct", "2-Oct", "2-Oct","2-Oct", "2-Oct", "3-Oct", "3-Oct", "3-Oct", "3-Oct"),
                   Product   = c("Milk", "Eggs", "Bread", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Beer", "Salad", "Apples", "Eggs", "Wine"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#    Customer OrderDate Product
# 1      John     1-Oct    Milk
# 2      John     2-Oct    Eggs
# 3      John     2-Oct   Bread
# 4       Tom     2-Oct Chicken
# 5       Tom     2-Oct   Pizza
# 6       Tom     2-Oct    Beer
# 7     Sally     3-Oct   Salad
# 8     Sally     3-Oct  Apples
# 9     Sally     3-Oct    Eggs
# 10    Sally     3-Oct    Wine
```

Post-tranformation:

```
datatransform <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6))
colnames(datatransform) <- c("Customer", "OrderDate", "Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4")
datatransform$Customer <- c("John", "John", "Tom", "Sally")
datatransform$OrderDate <- c("1-Oct", "2-Oct", "2-Oct", "3-Oct")
datatransform[1, 3:6] <- c("Milk", "", "", "") 
datatransform[2, 3:6 ] <- c("Eggs", "Bread", "", "")
datatransform[3, 3:6 ] <- c("Chicken", "Pizza", "Beer", "")
datatransform[4, 3:6 ] <- c("Salad", "Apples", "Eggs", "Wine")

#   Customer OrderDate Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
# 1     John     1-Oct     Milk                           
# 2     John     2-Oct     Eggs    Bread                  
# 3      Tom     2-Oct  Chicken    Pizza     Beer         
# 4    Sally     3-Oct    Salad   Apples     Eggs     Wine
```

Additionally, the number of columns for the products in the data frame must be equal to the maximum number of products bought by any customer on any single day.

Comment: since you have duplicates within date, add a new variable for the time, and this is a basic long-to-wide reshape: `data$time <- ave(data$Customer, data$Customer, FUN = seq_along); reshape(data, dir = 'wide', idvar = c('Customer','OrderDate'))`

Comment: Thank you, rawr, for the prompt solution! your solution resolves most of the problem. however, for John on oct2nd, it has an NA in Product1, Eggs in product 2 and Bread in product3. I would like to have eggs in product1 and bread in product 2. is there a way to fix that using reshape or otherwise?

Comment: I should have grouped by both customer and date `data$time <- with(data, ave(Customer, list(Customer, OrderDate), FUN = seq_along))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you talked about large dataset (then efficiency is a very important issue to toke into consideration), here is a dplyr and reshape2 solution:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data  %>% group_by(Customer, OrderDate) %>%
          mutate(ProductValue = paste0("Product", 1:n()) ) %>%
          dcast(Customer + OrderDate ~ ProductValue, value.var = "Product"  ) %>%
          arrange(OrderDate)

  Customer OrderDate Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
1     John     1-Oct     Milk     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2     John     2-Oct     Eggs    Bread     <NA>     <NA>
3      Tom     2-Oct  Chicken    Pizza     Beer     <NA>
4    Sally     3-Oct    Salad   Apples     Eggs     Wine
```

Comment: thank you both for the neat solutions. dplyr/reshape2 solution is fast on the large data set!